# The pronunciation of "Multiplicative"?

Tags: pronunciation

I've found two different versions of the pronunciation of "multiplicative".

- [Easier one for me](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GQEahfxNa8E) from YouTube.
- [Difficult one for me](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/multiplicative) from Merriam-Webster online dictionary.

And I also found that [some dictionary](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/spellcheck/english/?q=multiplicative) doesn't include this word..., [some](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/multiplicative) is not clear . So my questions are:

Which one is used by native speaker? (Or which one I should avoid?)

When speaking quickly, would some syllable of it be omitted? In this case, how to recognize/pronounce it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only pronunciation I've ever used or heard used (AmE) is the one used in your link to Merriam-Webster, with the stress on the third syllable.

I don't think it would ever be appropriate to omit a syllable in speech.